# nginx deny not working with return

Tags: nginx

I am trying to deny all access on a certain server block.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name myserver;
    root /srv/nkosl;

    deny all;

    location /mydistro {
            return 302 https://www.ubuntu.com/;
    }

    location /files {
            autoindex on;
    }
}
```

This denies access on *files* location (and successfully returns 403 forbidden message).

However I can still access myserver:8080/mydistro and it redirects me to ubuntu page.

How can I deny the /mydistro location as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to completely remove the `/mydistro` location. Or, at least, comment the line `return 302 https://www.ubuntu.com/;`.

To redirect selectively, try this:

```
location /mydistro {
    if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
        rewrite ^ https://www.ubuntu.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and then it works (returns 403), but that's not the point. I later want to add some IPs that will be able to access /mydistro and deny everyone else. Sorry if i didn't make myself clear in the beginning.

Comment: I see. Check my update, maybe you could use the `rewrite` command instead of raw redirect.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666877) describes why `allow`/`deny` does not work with `return`/`rewrite`.

one way to work around it is indeed using `if`s, however `if`s can be tricky in nginx in certain cases and `allow`/`deny` can also take a network mask...