# deny all not preventing return redirection

Tags: nginx

Nginx is behaving unexpectedly for me. Here are two simplified location blocks.

This works as expected. Returns 403 error:

```
location / {
    deny all;
    root /var/www/test;
}
```

I expected a 403 error. However, this returns 301 and redirects:

```
location / {
    deny all;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

How can I deny and prevent any url redirection with `return` directive?

Comment: From Wikipedia: _The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for permanent URL redirection_. The word _redirection_ means here that you must redirect, not just return the status code. Probably you just have to return some another code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In nginx, `return` directive is from rewrite module, and `deny` is from access module. According to [nginx document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) and source code, rewrite module is processed in `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE` phase (for `return` in location context), the access module is processed in `NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE` phase, rewrite phase happens before access phase, thus `return` stops request processing and returns 301 in rewrite phase.

Comment: Ah, that explains that behavior. Thank you. Is there any way to control access to the rewrite phase?

Comment: My reputation is too low for the upvote to show but I have marked yours as answering my question. Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @Layne or you could use `if` to control redirecting conditions, which if also from rewrite module.

Comment: I was avoiding using `if` just because of the [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article. Eventually, I would like to deny all requests except allow clients on a whitelist snippet that I created. I would prefer that the non-whitelist clients are not redirected before they are blocked.

Comment: @Layne use `if` is totally ok, I take that article as a reminder of its side effects. `if` is very powerful and convenient, do not miss it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny) ,

> The ngx_http_access_module module allows limiting access to certain client addresses.

You can't restrict access to another module [redirection module here].

To deny/prevent a redirection simply comment it by appending `#`

```
location / {
    deny all;
   # return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Commenting out the return code will not work for my situations though. Maybe a better example would be `deny 192.168.1.2;`. Even if I deny the client at that address in the next location block, they would would still get redirected and url changed. I don't want any of the denied zones to get redirected before they are denied access. Is there a better way to handle that?